# Resource Temporarily Unavailable when using fork()

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "safe-fork.h"
#include "split.h"

char **read_lines_input(char **args);
char **read_all_input(char **args);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
pid_t pid;

if(strcmp(argv[0], "-i") != 0) { 
    pid = safe_fork();

    if(pid < 0) {
    perror("Fork Didn't Work");
    exit(-1); 
    }

    else if(pid == 0) {
    if(argv[0] != NULL)  {
        int a; 
        a = execvp(argv[0], read_all_input(argv));

        if(a == -1) {
        perror("Execvp failed!");
        exit(-1); 
        }
    }

    else {
        int a; 
        a = execvp("echo", read_all_input(argv));

        if(a == -1) {
        perror("Execvp failed!");
        exit(-1); 
        }
    }

    exit(0); 
    }

    else {
    int status;

    status = wait(NULL); 

    if(status == -1) {
        perror("Child Exe Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}

else {
    char **temp;

    temp = read_lines_input(argv);

    while(temp != NULL) {
    pid = safe_fork();

    if(pid == 0) {
        if(argv[1] != NULL)
        execvp(argv[1], temp);

        else execvp("echo", temp);

        exit(-1); 
    }

    else {
        int status;

        wait(&status);

        if(status == -1) {
        perror("Child Exe Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        else return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    temp = read_lines_input(argv); 
    }
}

return 0;
}

char **read_all_input(char **args) {
char **input;
char *temp;
int i = 0; 

input = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);
temp = malloc(1000);

if(args[0] == NULL) {
    input[0] = malloc(5);
    strcpy(input[0], "echo");
    i++; 
}

else {
    while(args[i] != NULL) {
    input[i] = malloc(strlen(args[i]) + 1);
    strcpy(input[i], args[i]);
    i++; 
    }
}

while(fgets(temp, 1000, stdin) != NULL) {
    char **split_strings;
    int j = 0; 

    split_strings = split(temp);

    while(split_strings[j] != NULL) {
    input[i] = malloc(strlen(split_strings[j]) + 1);
    strcpy(input[i], split_strings[j]);
    i++;
    j++; 
    }
}

i++;
input[i] = NULL;

return input; 
}

char **read_lines_input(char **args) {
char **input;
char **split_strings; 
char *temp;
int i = 0;
int j = 1; 

input = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);
temp = malloc(1000);

if(args[1] == NULL) {
    input[0] = malloc(5);
    strcpy(input[0], "echo");
    i++; 
}

else {
    while(args[j] != NULL) {
    input[i] = malloc(strlen(args[j]) + 1);
    strcpy(input[i], args[j]);
    i++; 
    }
}

if(fgets(temp, 1000, stdin) == NULL)
    return NULL;

j = 0; 

split_strings = split(temp);

while(split_strings[j] != NULL) {
    input[i] = malloc(strlen(split_strings[j]) + 1);
    strcpy(input[i], split_strings[j]);
    i++;
    j++; 
}

i++;
input[i] = NULL;

return input; 
}
```

I keep getting an error when trying to use my fork, saying that the resources are temporarily unavailable.  I am testing it through my college's servers that I'm connected to.  Is it due to a fork bomb?  I don't understand why this is happening and would appreciate it if someone could help explain.  Safe-fork and split were provided to me from my professor.

d

Answer (score 1):

You likely have too many file descriptors open.  Either the limit for the server has been reached and can only be changed by root, or your user limit has been reached.  If it is a user limit, then you can change it.

### Check system file descriptor limit

```
# See system file descriptor max:
cat /proc/sys/file-max
# See number of file descriptors used:
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
```

### Check user descriptor limit

```
# See limit
ulimit -n
# See how much is used
lsof | wc -l
# Change limit
ulimit -Sn <number>
```

Comment: `lsof | wc -l` i got   9716. is this normal. I could mostly Google `.ldb` files are there

Answer (score 0):

This situation can come while compiling project with erroneous makefile(s) too.
Make will create too many threads and resource will be unavailable.

If this is the case , then you can give power cycle to PC and correct makefiles after reboot.